# AngularJS UI-view not loading with ngOptions on top

Tags: html, angularjs

New to `Angularjs`, when I include the select in the page the `ui-view` does not load. I see a blank page, but if I remove the select `ng-model`, everything seems ok. What am I missing? It is probably a noob mistake, Even if you could point me in the right direction it will be helpful.

```
        <!-- Header Bar -->
    <div class="row header">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="meta">
          <div class="page">
            Dashboard
          </div>
          <div class="breadcrumb-links">
            Home / Dashboard
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="page">
          <!--<div class="user pull-right">-->
          Role
          <select ng-model="$scope.selectedName" ng-options = "x for x in $scope.names">
        </div>
        <!--</div>-->
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- End Header Bar -->

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <div ui-view></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include `$scope` in `ng-model` or `ng-options`. Angular will assume those are scoped variables already.

Also you forgot to close your `<select>`.

Comment: Perfect. Silly me, sorry could not upvote for some reason.